# JQuery Simulating mouseover event is not working with chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that simulates `.mouseover()` event.

Here is a sample of the page that i'm trying to simulate that event.

```
<div class="hand card-stack" aria-disabled="false">
...
<div id="card-c181" class="card face-up ui-draggable">
    <div class="face"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
</div>
...
</div>
```

when i put the mouse on those `divs` the class value changes and i'm trying to write a script to detect the change of the class name automatically and my best idea was to simulate `.mouseover()`

so before i write the actual inject code i test them in chrome console and they work just fine but when i inject them they don't...

Here is my inject.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(main);    
});
function main()
{
  x = $('.card.face-up.ui-draggable').mouseover();
  alert("DONE");
}
```

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Testing",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Simulating mouseover",
  "homepage_url": "http://example.com",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js", "jquery-1.12.4.js"] ,
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Inject!"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
      "js": ["jquery-1.12.4.js"],
      "matches": ["https://*/*"]
  }],
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

So when i click on my extension button it just alerts and the mouseover don't work..
but in chrome console it works.
i've tried `.mouseenter()`, `.trigger("mouseover"),`.on` nothing worked in inject.js but in chrome console they works.

Comment: The reason it works in the console is that `$` refers to the page's jQuery. To access it your code should run in page context: [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks :) it finally worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script)